# Joomla 3, No bullets shown on frontend, only backend. (must be css)

Tags: css, joomla

I am new to CSS and have the following problem.

I have created a Joomla 3.3 site using a free template called Prismatic.
My problem arises when i write an article and use bullets at some point. 
Bullets show fine on the backend but i get nothing on the frontend.
After reading various posts and forums i got the idea it has to do with the template.css but thats as far as i can get..

My site demo address is "white.dr-tsekouras.gr" 
and the axact url where the bullets dont show is:
http://white.dr-tsekouras.gr/index.php/2014-10-13-12-15-44

Sorry the site is in greek

Can you please help ..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your own custom styling to your lists.

```
ul {
    list-style: disc;
}
```

Then, get these styles to be included when your website is loaded. The simplest way would be to create a separate CSS file, and reference it directly in your header.php file of your template.

Comment: The template CSS included in the CSS folder of the template has a part where lists are analyzed but i dont understand anything in there...

Comment: Just create your own CSS file, add your styles, upload it to the same folder, or one similar if you want to keep it separate, and then in the header just add a static url reference to your new CSS file.

Comment: Will try it and het back to you ... thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one...

There is

```
body {
    color: #fff;
}
```

on several places of your CSS. That means bullets are there, but white. Background is white as well. Remove that `color: #fff;`.

EDIT: Added DevTools print screen showing the problem:
[image: DevTools with the problem]

Comment: In which CSS file do you see that... can you give me a filename and line hint so i can go on locating the rest... 
Thanks again !!!

Comment: I added the print screen. Learn how to use developer console (press F12). You can see it is in colors.css.php file. I guess this file is generated from some settings. So you can probably change the white color in the configuration of the template.

Comment: In the colors.css.php file i change via firebug the following parameter:
body {
    color: #ffffff;
}
and everything is ok ... 
but when i try to edit the actual file i see the following piece of code :
body {
 color: ".$fontColorBase.";
}

So i change that to body {
 color: #000000;
}
and hope it would work but nothing !!!
Any ideas ?

Comment: How can i send you my colors.css.php file so you can have a better look ? If its ok with you ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the template configuration as I suggested? I believe you have a template called Prismatic for Joomla 3.x. I found there is a configuration for colors for this template: http://crosstec.de/templatedemos6/index.php/custom-colors.html. So edit colors there. Do not touch the code. Especially PHP code. Return it to it's previous state.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this from basics.css

```
ul {
list-style: outside;
padding-left: 0;
}
```

BTW, this template is pretty poorly coded. I'm anticipating it will give you more headaches than this!

Comment: I have done that as you said... and it worked on my subdomain (white.dr-tsekouras.gr) ... but i do the same on the main site (dr-tskouras.gr) and it doesn't work ... PLEASE HELP 
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Its working now..  i just copied al the css files from subdomain ... and paste the to domain css folder and it works now.

Comment: @JohnG Maybe you can mark my answer as correct then?